# :has:contains with variable instead of string

Tags: jquery, variables

I've got this code in jquery

```
$('.candidate-single:has(p:contains("Norfolk"))').addClass('is-hidden');
```

In place of where it says Norfolk I want to use a variable but can't seem to get it to work. I take it i need to escape the string somehow but can't quite work out how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you declare your variable :

```
var string = "Norflock"
```

you can use your code as it :

```
$('.candidate-single:has(p:contains("' + string + '"))').addClass('is-hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just break out of your single quotes:

`$('.candidate-single:has(p:contains("' + variable + '"))').addClass('is-hidden');`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variable instead of direct string then you can do in this way

```
var searchvariable=="Norfolk";
$('.candidate-single:has(p:contains("'+searchvariable+'"))').addClass('is-hidden');
```

Please share more detail if this is not helpful.